# Error with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hell. I'm trying to load data into a database and I'm getting the following error. Am I copying my file address incorrectly? Thanks.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'C:/New folder/calendar.txt' INTO TABLE calendar LINES TERMINATED BY  '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ;

MySQL said: Documentation

#2000 - Can't find file 'C:/New folder/calendar.txt'.
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to say Hello ;) If you're sure the file is there, check the permissions.

Comment: Oh yes. Hello, not hell haha. What are the permissions?

Comment: Maybe not the issue, but you need to be sure that mysql can see and has permission for the file. Are you running that LOAD from mysql command line?

Comment: I'm using a hosted website with database and phpmyadmin. I created a database and then I have this code from a book that I'm using (data analysis with sql) I saved the files on my C drive in the "new folder". How can I check to see if I have permission. I am at work ha.

Comment: This is kind of like if you worked for Ikea making those flat-pack furniture pieces, and instead of shipping all the necessary screws, put them in _your_ kitchen cupboard then wrote in the instructions "you'll find the screws in the kitchen cupboard", a statement that's blatantly untrue for your customers.

Answer (score 1):

The hosted website can't see your C drive. You will need to upload the file to the server. Use the phpmyadmin import function from the menu. That will allow you to upload a file from your PC.

Comment: Thanks. When I try to do that, I get this error. Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /cpsess7023159057/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Comment: Completely separate issue, @Stephertless, and not something that's on-topic to discuss here. Have you considered requesting help in a chatroom, or asking a friend to walk you through it? Or contacting the hosting company? This is a programming Q&A. Good luck.

Comment: @Stephertless - that's because you are at work and behind a proxy to keep you working ;) Try it from home.